# How to add props to a component instance in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I would like to know if it is posible to add a new prop to a component instance, the component instance look like this:

[image]

Maybe is a bad practice modifying a component instance directly, but I wonder if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using `React.cloneElement`:

```html
const changeProp = (component) => (
  {React.cloneElement(component, {
    someProp: { value }
  })}
)
```

Reference to react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement